# Strange behaviour with For Loops in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I have a problem with loops in opencl when I want to use counters in my loop to generate  values, It seems like the counters values remain constants during the iterations. My OpenCL function code is the following :

```
void my_loop( __global unsigned int* tab1, unsigned int* tab2){
  uint i, j;
  uint global_id_y = get_global_id(1);
  uint global_size_y = get_global_size(1);
  uint loop = global_size_y - global_id_y - 1
  uint length = get_global_size(0);

  for(i = 0; i < loop; i++){
      sidx = i * length; 
      for(j = 0; j < length; j++){
          tab2[sidx + j ] = i*10 + j;
      }
}
```

The code that calls the clEnqueueNDRangeKernel function

```
global_work_size[0] =  ncols; //ncols = 5
global_work_size[1] =  nbfrequents; //nbfrequents = 10

local_work_size[0] = ncols;
local_work_size[1] = nbfrequents;

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global_work_size, 
                                         local_work_size, 0, NULL, &event);
```

After execution, the results I obtained is something like this :

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 
...
0 1 2 3 4
```

Is it normal ? How can I do to use the differents values of my counters ?

Comment: what does length represent above?

Comment: Length represents the matrix width.

Comment: Post your source code, especially the code that calls `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`.  Perhaps your work dimensions or global work sizes have not been set correctly?

Comment: I updated the question with the code which calls ClEnqueueNDRangeKernel.

Comment: Your kernel code only depends on `get_global_id(1)`. This means that all work items sharing the same `global_id_y` do the exact same thing, which sounds like a bug. Besides, shouldn't `tab2` have an address space qualifier?

Comment: I detected the problem, it was caused by the value with the values of global_work_size and local_work_size, all the threads worked on all the matrix and not only a part of matrix as I wished. Thanks for your help.

Comment: All your work items fill same positions in **tab2** array with same values. The only difference is that each work item has different number of outer for-cycle loops. What should the output of your algorithm look like? Thanks.